# Find only repeated String attributes in list with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know below is the code to find out the occurrence of each String attributes in list , how can I filter this list with only duplicates item i.e having more than 1 occurrence. Sorry I am new to java 8 .

```
Map<String, Long> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                              Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 8):

create a stream from the `entrySet` and `filter`:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> result =  list.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                   .entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.getValue() >= 2)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you want to maintain a map then:

```
Map<String, Long> result = stringList().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getValue() >= 2)
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

on another note, if you just want the individual numbers that have more than  or equal to 2 occurrences then you can do:

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue() >= 2)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(toList());
```

another option being:

```
List<String> result = 
         list.stream()
             .filter(x -> list.stream().filter(x::equals).limit(2).count() == 2)
             .distinct()
             .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I would personally prefer filtering out based on a logic over creating stream twice.

Comment: `list.stream()
             .filter(x -> list.stream().filter..` was pointing out this.

Comment: Well, at least one such solution has been added to my answer. Just a choice to avoid using stream twice.

Comment: @nullpointer well creating a stream, in general, is a cheap operation. As for your solution using `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf`, I am not quite sure how that would be compared to my last suggestion performance wise. As for `Collections.frequency` I'd avoid that as it doesn't short circuit. imagine going through a list of thousands, millions of elements and all you're interested in is whether there is "2 or more occurrences of a particular object". the Stream solution above is efficient in the sense that it short-circuits.

Answer (score 7):

If your `List` is mutable, you can directly remove all elements except their second occurrence:

```
// example list
List<String> example = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(example, "foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "bar", "baz");

// actual operation
Map<String,Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
example.removeIf(s -> temp.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum)!=2);

// example output
example.forEach(System.out::println);// prints bar baz
```

The solution above keeps only one copy for each string having multiple occurrences while removing all strings having no duplicates. If you want to keep all duplicates and just remove those string not having duplicates, there is no way around determining the duplicate status first.

```
// same example input as above

// actual operation
Map<String,Boolean> temp = new HashMap<>();
example.forEach(s -> temp.merge(s, true, (a,b) -> false));
example.removeIf(temp::get);

// example output
example.forEach(System.out::println);// prints bar baz bar bar baz
```

Here, the temporary map can be created with a Stream operation with the same logic:

```
Map<String,Boolean> temp = example.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> true, (a,b) -> false));
example.removeIf(temp::get);
```

Answer (score 4):

The other way would be like this. after groupBy then remove entry with value=1;

```
result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
result.values().removeIf(v->v.intValue() == 1);
```

Comment: `result.entrySet().removeIf(v -> v.getValue() == 1);
        Set<String> res = result.keySet();` would be better I believe.. you can remove the entry instead of removing a value specifically from a list of values.

Comment: @nullpointer there is no difference between `result.values().removeIf(v -> == 1)` and `result.entrySet().removeIf(v -> v.getValue() == 1)`, except that the latter is more verbose. Both variants iterate over the map and remove matching entries.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to find that out could be

```
List<String> recurringItems = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> list.lastIndexOf(item) != list.indexOf(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since for items occurring more than once, *lastIndex* wouldn't be equal to the *first index*.

---

Alternatively, you can use `Collectors.toSet()` to ensure the items are listed only once in case you are not interested in their order of recurrence.

```
Set<String> recurringItemsOnce = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> list.lastIndexOf(item) != list.indexOf(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or using `Collections.frequency` as:

```
Set<String> recurringItems = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> Collections.frequency(list, item) >= 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: this would retrieve duplicate items, e.g. if our list was `Arrays.asList("1","2","3","1","56","4","4")` then as a result you'd have `[1, 1, 4, 4]` instead of `[1, 4]` which of course you could solve by adding a `distinct` call after the `filter`. on another note, it would be sufficient to keep it as is if the OP wants to get the occurrence of a particular number in the list which requires some additional searching... so ultimately it might be better to proceed with OP's approach.

Comment: @Aomine Indeed, if the eventual result is desired to just have the items `distinct` would help. Otherwise, if the sequence in which the duplicates occur matters, this can still be used. Added both for completeness.

Comment: Simpler in source code, but horrible regarding performance. The OP's original approach using `groupingBy` as starting point is much preferable.

Comment: @Holger Can you shed some details over the *horrible regarding performance* part. SInce I was considering that collecting to a Map using a stream and then performing operations would still be equal in performance.

Comment: `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` are linear searches. You can even predict, that for unique elements, all elements of the list will be traversed when searching once from the beginning and once from the end, and you are repeating this for *every element*, so the worst case of your operation will be *n×n*. In case of `frequency`, which counts all occurrences, it will always be *n×n*. Whereas the filling of the map will always be *n* operations, even if hash operation are more costly and it bears allocations, but that's a fixed constant factor, not growing with the number of elements.

Comment: @Holger True. Had thought over the `frequency` API performance earlier as well. I was overseeing the role of `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`part here.

Comment: Not really sure about why those downvotes. For those who have downvoted, does a solution not performant yet functional not supposed to be posted? (Not useful at all?)